# ui.bootstrap.datepicker is-open not working with a button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want open a datepicker when i click on a button.
Here is my view :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>   
  <div ng-controller="demo">    
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" ng-required="true" />
    <button style="height:34px;" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
      <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my controller

```
var demo = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
demo.controller('demo', function($scope) {
  $scope.dt = new Date();
  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

A plunker can be found here : http://plnkr.co/edit/AzASfL2t5DdIx1ayDOS5?p=preview

What i am doing wrong ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[FORKED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnFZdjzunQJhQEke3yWn?p=preview)**

You have to add the `ng-click` `$event` property in your `open()` method and do an `$event.preventDefault()` and `$event.stopPropagation()` to open ui-bootstrap's datepicker.

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
var demo = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
demo.controller('demo', function($scope) {
  $scope.dt = new Date();
  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

*HTML*

```
<button style="height:34px;" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
  <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it works perfectly ! But can you explain me what these function do ? Thx

Comment: Having a disabled attribute on the <input> will also cause the datepicker to not display.