# Angular datepaicker works in minial project, not in full-blown

Tags: angularjs, android-datepicker

I have a bare bones, minimalistic app, which includes this in the HTML of a view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"   
is-open="popup1.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"  
datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"  
ng-required="true" close-text="Close"   
alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />

<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">  
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

and this in the controller

```
$scope.open1 = function() {
   $scope.popup1.opened=true;
}

$scope.popup1 ={'opened': false}
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

When I click the calendar icon in the demo project, the calendar pops open, but it does not in my full-blown project, even when I copy/paste the code ($scope.popup1.opened does change from false to true when clicked).

The full blown project is too large to post - any advice?

---

[Update] Thanks for the help. One point to notice is that the code works in a minmial project, but not in a full-blown project, regardless of the suggested duplicate question.

However, I have taken on board the suggested duplicate an, alas, it does not help.

```
   $scope.SwallowClick = function($event)
   {
      if ($event.cancelable) 
          $event.preventDefault();

        $event.stopPropagation();   

      return false;   // don't handle event further
   }

    $scope.open1 = function($event)
   {
        $scope.SwallowClick($event);
        $scope.popup1.opened=true;
        return false;   // don't handle event further
   }
```

Comment: @PankajParkar Do you have any idea where I can look?

Comment: I think duplicated marked answer is correct

Comment: I read it, and it does not help. I have updated hte question. Thank you so veyr much for trying to help me, though

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.. I'm gonna reopen it..

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this question and the accepted answer? [ui.bootstrap.datepicker is-open not working with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123883/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-is-open-not-working-with-a-button)

Try passing $event to your ng-click handler, like this...

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)">  
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

And then in your javascript, something like this...

```
$scope.open1 = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.popup1.opened=true;
}

$scope.popup1 ={'opened': false}
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

Comment: Upvote, but, alas, it does not help. Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!   `$scope.format`was not defined (blush)